# Jacoco showing 0% coverage even test cases are executed successfully while using @PrepareForTest annaotation

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock

Jacoco  showing 0% coverage even test cases are executed successfully  when I am using @PrepareForTest annaotation.

Below are mine  sample code. I want to test WebOmnibarLookupServiceImpl  class public method loadWebOmnibarLookupCache(). in side its calling private method getWebOmnibarDictionaryKey.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({QueryRequestUpdater.class, WebOmnibarLookupServiceImpl.class})
public class WebOmnibarLookupServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private WebOmnibarLookupServiceImpl service = new WebOmnibarLookupServiceImpl();
   @Test
    public void testloadWebOmnibarLookupCache() throws Exception {
        WebOmnibarLookupServiceImpl privateService = PowerMock.createPartialMock(WebOmnibarLookupServiceImpl.class, "getWebOmnibarDictionaryKey");
        PowerMock.expectPrivate(privateService, "getWebOmnibarDictionaryKey", TestData.getSearchQueryRequestDTOForCache()).andReturn(TestData.getWebOmnibarDictionaryKey());
        doReturn(TestData.getSearchResponseObj()).when(webOmnibarDictionaryCache).get(any());
        service.loadWebOmnibarLookupCache(TestData.getSearchQueryRequestDTOForCache());
    }
}
```

Maven Configuration:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>sonar-coverage</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
              <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <append>true</append>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*Config.*</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*Constants.*</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*Enum.*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>


                <execution>
                  <id>default-instrument</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>instrument</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                  <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                  <id>report</id>
                  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage.exec</dataFile>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>


              <execution>
                <id>agent-for-it</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Here I am using @@PrepareForTest({ WebOmnibarLookupServiceImpl.class}) to mock private method. 
   Here test executed successfully but coverage showing 0% for this class only those class are not added @PrepareForTest showing coverage percentage.
        I am geeting below warning message while execute testcases.

```
    [WARNING] Classes in bundle 'webanalytics-server' do no match with execution data. For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
    [WARNING] Execution data for class com/shn/webanalytics/service/impl/WebOmnibarLookupServiceImpl does not match.
```

Answer (score 3):

I see that you are using `PowerMock`. There is a known issue of jacoco and powermock compatibility. You can find more details [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo).

One of the solution is you can do offline jacoco instrumentation on the code instead of on the fly instrumentation.

[Here](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom-offline.xml) is one of the example done in maven for offline instrumentation.

Comment: Thank you . I have added offline instrumentation on maven. while executing test cases I am getting message like Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class com/shn/webanalytics/WebAnalyticsServiceProvider is already instrumented.

Comment: My maven configuration is below

Comment: added my maven configuration in question section. I am getting  Class com/shn/webanalytics/WebAnalyticsServiceProvider is already instrumented

Comment: executing maven goal is org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent